# Trying to replace na values for a a column with same key but has a value for one of the rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have a data frame,

```
data.frame(Primary_key = c(100,100,100,100,200,200,200) , 
           values= c("buyer",NA,NA,NA,"seller",NA,NA))
```

I'm trying to get a desired output of,

```
data.frame(Primary_key = c(100,100,100,100,200,200,200) , 
           values= c("buyer","buyer","buyer","buyer","seller","seller","seller"))
```

This is a simplified version the original has 3 possible values and over 10,000 different primary keys.

Thinking of a `dplyr` way to do this but kind of stumped.

I'm trying to `group_by` the primary key and then use a `replace` function.

Comment: ```library(tidyr); fill(your_data_frame, values, .direction =  "down")```

Comment: what if the NA's are in between like (na , buyer, na,na)

Comment: I posted an answer which addresses your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::fill` and `dplyr::group_by` together:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Primary_key) %>% 
  fill(values, .direction = "downup")
```

```
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#> # Groups:   Primary_key [4]
#>    Primary_key values
#>          <dbl> <fct> 
#>  1          50 <NA>  
#>  2         100 buyer 
#>  3         100 buyer 
#>  4         100 buyer 
#>  5         100 buyer 
#>  6         200 seller
#>  7         200 seller
#>  8         200 seller
#>  9         300 both  
#> 10         300 both
```

***Sample data:*** This data considers different cases that would happen in the actual data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Primary_key = c(50,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,300,300), 
                  values= c(NA, NA,"buyer",NA,NA,"seller",NA,NA,NA,"both"))
```